# Textbox visibility by using array of Radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating an array of radio buttons to get information about if the user has certain disease or not. For that i'm creating array of radio buttons in which the disease name are stored in an array and retrieved to create separate radiobuttons based on their names whenever the **add** buttons is clicked.

**HTML Code:**

```
 <div>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">&nbsp<img style="padding-bottom: 15px;" 
 src="images/add_btn.png"></a>
 </div>
```

Here I'm using Javascript to create the radiobutton on **add** button click. And I'm also creating a hidden textbox along with the controls which on selection Yes in the radiobutton it gets visible to the user in the screen.

**Javascript to create controls**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var values = new Array();
<?php foreach($value as $key => $val){ ?>
    values.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
<?php } ?>

var maxField = values.length; //Input fields increment limitation
var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
var x = 0; //Initial field counter is 1

var fieldHTML = '<div class="field_wrapper"><div class="label-group"><div class="line"></div><label style="font-weight: 900;" id="labelid">Disease</label></div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Disease" id="inlineRadio1" value="Yes" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();"><label class="form-check-label radio-inline" for="inlineRadio1">Yes</label>&nbsp&nbsp
<div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden; display:inline-block;"><input type="text" name="dvalue" id="dvalue" placeholder="Value" size="5" style="font-size:11px;"/></div></div><div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Disease" id="inlineRadio2" value="No" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">No</label>
</div><div class="line"></div></div>'; 

//Once add button is clicked
$(addButton).click(function(){
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if(x < maxField){ 
         var element=values[x];
         $(wrapper).prepend(fieldHTML); //Add field html
         document.getElementById("labelid").innerText = element;//label
         document.getElementById("inlineRadio1").name = element;//yes radio
         document.getElementById("inlineRadio2").name = element;//no radio
         document.getElementById("dvalue").name = element;//textbox
         x++;//Increment field counter
    }
});

});
</script>
```

**Javascript to control visibility of textbox**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function yesnoCheck() 
{
  if (document.getElementById('inlineRadio1').checked) 
  {
     document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  else 
  {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }

}
</script>
```

Now, the problem I'm facing here is in the Visibility. When I first create one set of controls the visibility works fine like in the image.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

But when i create another set of control means i can't able to change the visibility of the previously created controls.

[image: Step 3]

Here I have selected Yes radio button for Diabetes but the textbox is still hidden.

Please provide me a solution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you are using id, if (document.getElementById('inlineRadio1').checked)  it always triggers the first id in the body, try implementing this with class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this:

```js
var values = [ 'Disease', 'Diabetes', 'AIDS', 'Hepatitis', 'Heart Disease', 'Other' ],
    html = '<div class="field_wrapper"><span style="font-weight: 900;">Disease</span>:&nbsp;<select name="Disease" onchange="yesnoCheck( this )"><option value="Yes">Yes</option><option value="No" selected>No</option></select>&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="dvalue" placeholder="Value" size="5" /></div>',
    x = 0;

function yesnoCheck( el ) {
  var val = ( el.options[ 0 ].selected ) ? 'text' : 'hidden';

  $( el ).next( 'input' ).attr( 'type', val )
}

$( '.add_button' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ( x < values.length ) {
    $( '.disease' ).append( html );
    $( '.field_wrapper:last span' ).text( values[ x ] );
    $( '.field_wrapper:last select' ).attr( 'name', values[ x ] );
    x++
  }
} )
```

```css
.add_button {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: transparent url(https://image.ibb.co/hZbOA8/add_button.png) no-repeat
}
.field_wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="add_button" title="Add field"></a>
<div class="disease"></div>
```

**Edit:** Using `Radio buttons` instead of `Select box`:

```js
var values = [ 'Disease', 'Diabetes', 'AIDS', 'Hepatitis', 'HeartDisease', 'Other' ],
    html = '<div class="field_wrapper"><span style="font-weight: 900;">Disease</span>:&nbsp;<label for="inlineRadioNo"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Disease" id="inlineRadioNo" value="No" onclick="yesnoCheck( this )" checked>No</label>&nbsp;<label for="inlineRadioYes"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Disease" id="inlineRadioYes" value="Yes" onclick="yesnoCheck( this )">Yes</label><input type="hidden" name="dvalue" placeholder="Value" size="5" /></div>',
    x = 0;

function yesnoCheck( el ) {
  var val = $( el ).val() == 'Yes' ? 'text' : 'hidden';

  $( 'input[placeholder="Value"]' ).eq( $( 'input[type="radio"]:checked' ).index( el ) ).attr( 'type', val )
}

$( '.add_button' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ( x < values.length ) {
    $( '.disease' ).append( html );
    $( '.field_wrapper:last span' ).text( values[ x ] );
    $( '.field_wrapper:last label:first' ).attr( 'for', 'inlineRadioNo' + x );
    $( '.field_wrapper:last label:last' ).attr( 'for', 'inlineRadioYes' + x );
    $( '.field_wrapper:last input[value="No"]' ).attr( { id: 'inlineRadioNo' + x, name: 'inlineRadio' + x } );
    $( '.field_wrapper:last input[value="Yes"]' ).attr( { id: 'inlineRadioYes' + x, name: 'inlineRadio' + x } );
    $( '.field_wrapper:last input:last' ).attr( 'name', values[ x ] )
    x++
  }
} )
```

```css
.add_button {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: transparent url(https://image.ibb.co/hZbOA8/add_button.png) no-repeat
}
.field_wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="add_button" title="Add field"></a>
<div class="disease"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine. But i need to use Radio buttons instead of Select box.